# Counting problem combinatorics with employees of a faculty.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

It is a problem of a fictitious faculty. Let the number of employees be $n=k+m$, Also there are three named people let's say *Ann,* *Boris* and *Cain.*
Out of $n$ employees there are $m$ regular professors. There are three different scenarios.

1) 
How many ways are there to put all $n$ employees into a row if Ann and Boris have to stand together and Cain has to be after them? 
So for this i know have to look at Ann and Boris as a package, but i don't know how to include all the criteria, because Cain has to be after them, so there are less options, but i don't know how to apply this restriction.

2) 
Same as before, just that there is only this restriction: after every regular professor there are two employees that aren't regular professors.
If i understand this correctly, i should just look at the other $k$ people for this two. Perhaps it would be like: $\binom{m}{1}\binom{k}{2}$ or  am i mistaken?

3) 
This one is a little different.
 How many ways are there such that all $n$ employees can do occupational safety in $5$ different  time slots if there should be at least 2 employees in each time slot?
So this last one is confusing at how can i look at every possibility.
So any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a handle on the first one, note that swapping the Ann–Boris unit for Cain turns a good row into a bad row, and *vice versa*.  Also note that within the Ann–Boris unit, Ann and Boris may be arranged in either order.

I think the second one needs to be specified more clearly.  Assuming that there is no longer any restriction on Ann, Boris, or Cain, and that at least two employees who are not regular professors must immediately follow each regular professor in the row, my approach would be to let $R$ represent a regular professor slot and $O$ an other employee slot.  I would then define a unit $U=ROO$ consisting of a regular professor slot followed by two other employee slots.  Then I would compute how many words can be made with $m$ $U$s and $k-2m$ $O$s.  Then reexpanding each $U$ as $ROO$, I would account for the the number of ways of arranging $m$ regular professors in the $R$ slots and $k$ other employees in the $O$ slots.

For the third one, you might use the principle of inclusion–exclusion.  There are $5^n$ ways to assign time slots to employees, but in some of these assignments at least one of the time slots will be assigned to fewer than two employees.  These bad assignments must be subtracted.  To this end, let $S_{\{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_a\},\{j_1,j_2,\ldots,j_b\}}$ be the set of assignments in which time slots $i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_a$ each contain only one employee, and time slots $j_1,j_2,\ldots,j_b$ each contain no employee.  So at least $t=a+b$ of the five time slots contain fewer than two employees.  Then
$$
\lvert S_{\{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_a\},\{j_1,j_2,\ldots,j_b\}}\rvert={}_nP_a\cdot(5-t)^{n-a},
$$
since there are ${}_nP_a$ ways to place employees in time slots $i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_a$ and $(5-t)^{n-a}$ ways to place the remaining $n-a$ employees in time slots.  By the principle of inclusion–exclusion, the number of valid assignments is
$$
f_n=\sum_{t=0}^5(-1)^t\sum_{{A,B}\atop{\lvert A\rvert+\lvert B\rvert=t}}\lvert S_{A,B}\rvert.
$$
Since there are $\binom{5}{a}\binom{5-a}{t-a}$ ways to choose a set $A$ of size $a$ and a disjoint set $B$ of size $t-a$, this expression becomes
$$
f_n=\sum_{t=0}^5(-1)^t\sum_{a=0}^t\binom{5}{a}{}_nP_a\binom{5-a}{t-a}(5-t)^{n-a}.
$$
The sequence $f_n$ does not appear to be in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, but the analogous sequences for $2$, $3$, or $4$ time slots are in the Encyclopedia ([A052515](http://oeis.org/A052515), [A224541](http://oeis.org/A224541), [A224542](http://oeis.org/A224542)).  The sequence $f_n$ does, however, appear as the fifth column of the two-dimensional array [A200091](http://oeis.org/A200091).